# Rest api - Defining URL for hierarchical level data

Tags: rest, api, http, url, vert.x

I have concept of Account and sub-account.

```
Account
   |--->Subaccount1
            |----> Subaccount2
                       |---->Subaccount3
                             ....................... and so on
```

```
Account level rest url's:
POST - base_url/accounts
PUT - base_url/accounts
GET - base_url/accounts/$acc_name
DELETE - base_url/accounts/$acc_name
GET - base_url/accounts
```

```
Subaccount level rest url's - level 1
POST - base_url/accounts/$acc_name/subaccount
PUT - base_url/accounts/$acc_name/subaccount
GET - base_url/accounts/$acc_name/subaccount/$sub_acc
DELETE - base_url/accounts/$acc_name/subaccount/$sub_acc
GET - base_url/accounts/$acc_name/subaccount
```

If the sub-account level is 1 or known, i can define URL.
But since i doesn't know the hierarchy level, How will i define URL for sub-accounts?

For defining routers, i m making use of vertx framework.

Answer (score 1):

In the Vertx Web module documentation is stated that [you can use a regex to define how your URL will look like](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/js/#_routing_by_paths_that_begin_with_something). The easiest way would be to define a route `/accounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}/*` that takes care of handling nth level of depth

However, while possible, **I strongly recommend you against this pattern**. This will make your URLs highly nested and can bring you troubles in the future. A better (and much more simple) approach would be to consider a subaccount a first class citizen so you'd have

- `/accounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}` for "first" level nested subaccounts
- `/subaccounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}` for "nth" level nested subaccounts

Or even considering that a subaccount is an account itself, in that case you don't need the second URL

Comment: Considering subaccount as account, will it not violates the concept?

Comment: We're talking about business rules here, so you will know much more than any of us. In your domain, a subaccount may have some peculiarities that a "regular account" doesn't. In other, a subaccount is just a regular account linked to another one. When designing your API, you should always have two things in mind: what you are exposing and how it should be consumed by a client. Yes, sometimes we have to add some client requisites, but try to make your API as generic as possible

Answer (score 0):

Frankly? I wouldn't do it via nesting, especially not, if you have a depth of `n`.

Just make the unique identifier of the sub-accounts usable on the `/accounts` endpoint.

In the end, a sub-account is a subset of an account. Therefore I think this is pretty acceptable.

If you really want to split it, rather do something like that:

```
/accounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}
```

Comment: How will i define for nth level of subaccounts? Will it be "/accounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}/subaccounts/{id}...."? If it is so, how will i get the value of path param in code. I m making use of vertx-routers.

Comment: Pelocho answered that, I just answered this question regardless of vert.x (since I never used it) ;)